# Validate at compile time property names in application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, validation, properties, annotations, application.properties

I want to check if it is possible to validate the property names at compile time and not at runtime.
My application.yml needs to have data ilke this-

```
  john:
    firstName: John
    lastName: Doe
    age: 30
    address: efghhhhh
    email: john.doe@gmail.com
```

My ApplicationProperties.java is like this -

```
@Data
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:employee.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class ApplicationProperties {

    private Employee john;
}
```

And my Controller gets the data like this -

```
private final ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;
applicationProperties.getJohn();
```

I want to make sure if someone by mistake changes "john" to "joohn", it should throw an error at compile time. Right now the compilation works fine and it throws a NullPointerException at runtime. Is it possible to achieve a compile time check for the property name? If so, please let me know how to do that?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at compile time, but you can make sure the application fails fast by creating `@Validated @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "john")` for your props and putting validation rules like `@NotNull` on top of the relevant properties.

See [here](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot) for more information.